# Extbase routeEnhancers for Speaking URLs without page segment in TYPO 9.5.x

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I'm searching for a setup to achieve following speaking urls:

- domain.tld > homepage PID 1
- domain.tld/path-to-article1 > detail PID 2 with extbase show action
- domain.tld/path-to-article2 > detail PID 2 with extbase show action

Instead of this the URLs are

- domain.tld/detail/path-to-article1
- domain.tld/detail/path-to-article2

How can I remove the detail path segment and keep the extbase plugin on PID2/detail

Answer (score 2):

Your question never mentions clear which extension you want to configure, also you never provide the example you're using.
So I just post the configuration I'm using for the extension news (tx_news, NOT tt_news) and I assume it should work like you desired:

```
routeEnhancers:
  NewsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      -
        routePath: '/{news_title}'
        _controller: 'News::detail'
        _arguments:
          news_title: news
    defaultController: 'News::detail'
    aspects:
      news_title:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: tx_news_domain_model_news
        routeFieldName: path_segment
```

If you use another extension you've to adjust the corresponding parts accordingly.

Details about `RouteEnhancers` can be found [here](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-core/master/en-us/Changelog/9.5/Feature-86365-RoutingEnhancersAndAspects.html) (till today 5. Aug. 2019 the only longer official explanation can be found in the changelog).

Comment: Your example did not give an answer to this question. I still see the page 'detail' in the URL `domain.tld/news//detail/name-title-news-article`

Comment: @TYPO3UA Then you new configuration is not working yet for some reason. Stating that my example is no answer to the question is just wrong.

Comment: I do not write that your example is not correct. I used your example but I cannot remove the segment 'detail' from URL. I still see the page `detail` in the URL `domain.tld/news/detail/name-title-news-article`

Comment: clear the cache. Typo3 is caching file-contents and in the case of a changed file the cache has to be cleared, else you still work with the old file-content.

Comment: :) I know it and I did do it... My the tree of pages look as
```- Root (0 level)
-- News (1 level)
--- Detail (2 level)``` and My URL `domain.tld/news/detail/name-title-news-article`

Comment: @TYPO3UA then the `detail` is coming from the page-tree and is no path-segment of the Route-Enhancer. You can configure news that list and detail-view are shown on the same page and then you can remove the detail-page.

Comment: I understand it... but this is bad that I can not remove from URL this segment... for example in the RealURL has for each page the option `Exclude from speaking URL:`

Comment: I don't see a reason that you need for details another page than for the list but if so, then you've be creative. you could move the detail-page outside and parallel to the list-page, think about a useful path-segement i.e. "article" or "news-article" instead of "detail".

Comment: Oh, it is not a bad idea. I think that I will do it that way. Thank You so much for the hint.